# What can I do with an HP Touchpad now that Open webOS will not support it?

Tags: tablet

HP [confirmed](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/hp-touchpad-palm-tablet-webos,16575.html) that the Touchpad will not be upgradeable to Open webOS. The version of webOS that it shipped with arguably was not production ready. With few apps and an outdated browser, is there anything the hardware could be used for?

Answer (score 0):

Put android on it! [Like them](http://liliputing.com/2012/01/how-to-install-android-4-0-on-the-hp-touchpad-cyanogenmod-9-alpha.html).